# Solving Triangle Word Problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A ship leaves port for a remote island 34 miles west and 60 miles south of the port. Find the distance and bearing to the remote island.

What would the diagram look like to this problem? and what would the bearing be?

Answer (score 1):

The diagram would look like a right triangle.  One leg has length 34 pointed left.  From the end of that, the other leg points down with length 60.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought and how would I find the bearing?

Comment: You find the bearing with an arctangent function.

Comment: Okay thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be $68.96$ after using Pythagorean theorem ($a^2+b^2=c^2$).

$$ \sqrt{4756}\approx 68.96.$$